# Ajax / Jquery show (non bootstrap) popup / model after div reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a new to ajax an jquery and I am trying to accomplish the folowing:

Let user click on the button to open a model popup (no bootstrap) and press a button to update the SQL database, the update is send by ajax post method to the update php. After the update is succesfull i reload the div in ajax. The popup is closed after this update event accured. What I want is the popup model to stay open (or atleast reopen) after the div is reloaded. I need this so the new info that is put in the SQL database is refreshed and the user sees what has happend.

I use the folowing scripts to accomplish this but the popup is not showing after the reload (no errors).

All help is welcome and I am sorry for my language as english is not my main language..

Script to post the value to update php

```
  <script>
    function post(house) {
        
        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./execute_.php",
        data: {house: house},
        success: function(r) {
            
            $("#mymodelestate").show();
            $("#estaterefresh").load("content.php");
        
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("ERROR : Something went wrong! Try again or contact the database administrator" + error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

The div tags with inside the modal:

```
<div id="mymodelestate" class="modalestate">
 <div class="modalestate-content">
    <span class="closeestate">&times;</span>
... the content ...
</div></div>
```

The script to open the model with the content

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("mymodelestate");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("btnestate");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeestate")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}</script>
```

Comment: where is that modal located inside estaterefresh div ?

Comment: Yes, tries to just do the modal. Result is a double page

Comment: No matter what I try I end up with double pages inside the modal

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate double pages ?

Comment: Hi, after the refresh the original webppage is loaded within the modal instead of the content that is within the modal.

Comment: Just to be clear in what i am trying to accomplish. I need the php variables refreshed within the modal without the model closes after the update. I am using on click so the modal doesnt close but the refresh of the data is not working yet as the modal closes after reset or shows the original webpage within the modal. When reloading and manualy clicking and opening the modal all is fine

Comment: other option would be bringing data which you need to display in modal in json format and then add them inside your inputs.